# TeamCity LDAP Synchronization does not create new users

Tags: active-directory, ldap, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I've configured LDAP for TeamCity. First sync trail fail. According to the teamcity-ldap.log all users were found but no created:

[2015-01-30 08:04:53,077]   INFO -     jetbrains.buildServer.LDAP - User ... (remote ID: 'CN=...,OU=Users,OU=...,DC=...,DC=...') should be created, but automatic user creation is disabled.

I set teamcity.options.createUsers to true but no users were created.

[2015-01-30 08:13:26,375] INFO - jetbrains.buildServer.LDAP - Found 224 search results for search base='OU=Users,OU=....', filter='(objectClass=User)', scope=2, attributes=[mail, sAMAccountName, displayName]

[2015-01-30 08:13:26,375] INFO - jetbrains.buildServer.LDAP - Last synchronization statistics: created users=0, updated users=0, deleted users=0, remote users=224, matched users=2, created groups=0, updated groups=0, deleted groups=0, remote groups=0, matched groups=0, duration=250ms, errors=[]

What do I have to change that the users are created?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option:

```
teamcity.options.users.synchronize.createUsers=true
```

was not set.

From JetBrains:
Note: it is not recommended to use teamcity.options.users.synchronize.createUsers=true option, because it can be removed in the future versions of TeamCity.
As for now TeamCity can automatically create users in TeamCity, if they are found in one of the mapped LDAP groups and groups synchronization is turned on via teamcity.options.groups.synchronize option. So please confgure group synchronization.